# How to resolve “CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'bool''” compilation error?

Tags: c#

The compiler shows error

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'bool'.

I don't understand why `Console.WriteLine(Сalculate)` does not output. Thank you for answer.
The code here:

```
public static double Calculate(string userInput)
{
    var parts = userInput.Split(' ');
    var sum = double.Parse(parts[0]);
    var rate = double.Parse(parts[1]);
    var time = double.Parse(parts[2]);
    return sum * (1 - Math.Pow(rate/ rate, time)) / (1 - rate/ rate);
}

static void Main()
{
    Calculate(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Сalculate);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You should pass in parameters to `Сalculate`, now you are passing the method in to `WriteLine`..

Comment: Third line of `Main`: `Console.WriteLine(Сalculate)` but `Сalculate` is a function.

Comment: Basically you need to capture the return of `Calculate` in a variable and then use that in `Console.WriteLine`.  Or just do it all in one line `Console.WriteLine(Calculate(Console.ReadLine()));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // get result from your method
    var result = Calculate(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadKey();
    // print result
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```